# ASP.NET MVC API model not parsing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am having some problems parsing my model in ASP.NET MVC API

This is my API controller:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    // Hent liste af personer
    public IEnumerable<UserModel> Get()
    {
        return new UserModel[] { new UserModel(), new UserModel() };
    }

    // Hente enkelt person
    public UserModel Get(int id)
    {
        return new UserModel();
    }

    // Opret person
    [ValidationActionFilter]
    public CreateUserRespose Post([FromBody]UserModel model)
    {
        CreateUserRespose rs = new CreateUserRespose();
        return rs;
    }

    // Rediger person
    public UserModel Put(int id, [FromBody]UserModel model)
    {
        return new UserModel();
    }

    // Slet person
    public UserModel Delete(int id)
    {
        return new UserModel();
    }
}
```

}

And the UserModel:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public String FristName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public String Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String MatrikelId { get; set; }
}
```

When I call though Fiddler to the Post command with the following body

```
FirstName=Fistname MiddleName&LastName=SomeName&Email=email@email.us&MatrikelId=1234
```

Will the action Post be called, but the model is null, and ModelState.IsValid is true, the same happens if I send no data with the body!
What am I doing wrong here?

Update:
I have tryed sending the data as json instead
Fiddler:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:51268
Content-Length: 102
Content-type: application/json

{"FristName":"Kasper asdasd","LastName":"asdasdasd","Email":"asdaasd@asdasd.us","MatrikelId":"132456asd"}
```

But should the model state not be invalid when the model is null?

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` header value in your request?

Comment: I have not set one in fiddler the headders are the following "User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:51268
Content-Length: 79"

Comment: try removing the `[FromBody]` infront of the parameters

Comment: @Aviatrix i have tryed that, did not work

Comment: In that case please set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` it should resolve the issue. If you confirm it was your issue I will describe details in answer.

Comment: @tpeczek can you write that as an anwser so i can accept it? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASP.NET Web API is using *content negotiation* process in order to decide which `MediaTypeFormatter` to use for deserializing the body of the request. For the typical POST request it will check for `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers. If none is present it will use the first `MediaTypeFormatter` on the list (by default it is `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`).

In your case Web API was unable to determine the proper `MediaTypeFormatter`. Adding a `Content-Type` header with value of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to the request should resolve the issue.

If you want to get more detailed knowledge regarding *Formatters*, *Model Binding* and *Content Negotiation* in ASP.NET Web API I would suggest following reading:

- [Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET -> Chapter 8. Formatters and Model Binding](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449337711/ch_formatters_and_model_binding.html) (you should look very close at the entire book if you are interesed in learning ASP.NET Web API)
- [Everything you want to know about ASP.NET Web API content negotiation](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/07/everything-you-want-to-know-about-asp-net-web-api-content-negotation/)